# How to write xml file like this format?

Tags: c#, xml

I want write code in c# which i need to get like this .

```
<Email version="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"> </Email>
```

I have tried this but not exact.

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\nefe.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Email");
writer.WriteString("version=2.00  xmlns=Http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

and output this code is giving like this

```
 <Email>version=2.00 xmlns=Http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe</Email>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well yes - you're calling `WriteString`, which writes text content. Your sample XML contains *attributes*, so you should be using [`WriteAttributeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring.aspx):

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.00");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");
```

Do you *have* to use `XmlWriter` though? Personally I'd recommend using LINQ to XML if you *possibly* can. It's not as suitable for writing enormous documents which `XmlWriter` can handle easily, but it's *much* cleaner when you're just trying to create a simple document of moderate size:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe";
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement(ns + "Email",
                                     new XAttribute("xmlns", ns.ToString()),
                                     new XAttribute("version", "2.00")));
doc.Save("nefe.xml");
```

If you *do* insist on using `XmlWriter`, you should use a `using` statement to make sure the output is always closed even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

The method you're looking for on `XmlTextWriter` is `WriteAttributeString`

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\nefe.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Email");
writer.WriteAttributeString("version","2.00");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","Http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/EZU91552